# Base URL is changing when making Ajax call

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP 3.x app with some APIs being called from AJAX.

On AJAX I call the url like so:

```
url: 'user/id/' + id,
method: 'get',
dataType: 'json'
// ...
```

Etc..

My url is http://localhost:8090/users

So the url on ajax is like 
http://localhost:8090/currentpage/users/id/

But for some reason sometimes the url changes to http://localhost:8090/users/id/

What should I change?
What is happening?

Comment: You should try to figure out what "sometimes" really means here. If it only happens on specific pages, or after specific operations, then you can look at those areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of your action(parameter) in URL.

Here are some examples so you can understand it better.

Let consider we have a link to every page of our project.
Click Here to add a new user

This link will create different URL depending on your current URL

```
Current URL                                       URL generate by LINK
localhost/products  (here index is the method)    localhost/users/add
localhost/products/add                            localhost/products/users/add
localhost/products/edit/1                         localhost/products/edit/users/add
```

To fix this issue, use a "/" at the beginning and provide the path from your webroot

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you (:

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is correct.

On how to solve it, what I commonly do is save the webroot as returned from CakePHP in a javascript variable. By doing this in the header of the template file it will be available everywhere:

```
<!-- src/Templates/Layout/default.ctp -->
<head>
    <script>
         var webroot = <?= $this->request->webroot ?>
    </script>
</head>
```

When you then want to create a Ajax call, use this URL as generated from Javascript:

```
url: webroot + "user/id" + id //...
```

Now the call will be as expected, regardless of where your application is placed on the webserver.